# CSS applied for one endpoint but not for another in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flashcards</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/style.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game_container">
        <!-- TITLE -->
        <h1>Flashcards</h1>

        <!-- CARDS CONTAINER -->
        <div class="cards_container">

            <!-- FIRST CARD -->
            <div class="cards">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front"><p>France</p></div>
                    <div class="back"><p>Francoise Meyers</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ...OTHER CARDS -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPT FOR CARD ROTATION -->
    <script>
    // Select all elements with the class "card"
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

    cards.forEach(card => {
        // Add event listener for click
        card.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Toggle styles on click
            if (card.style.transform === 'rotateY(180deg)') {
                // If already rotated, revert back to original state
                card.style.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
            } else {
                // Otherwise, rotate the card
                card.style.transform = 'rotateY(180deg)';
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see I have some href provided for css in the html file above, which works for the default endpoint - `localhost:8080`. But if I try to indicate custom endpoint (`"api/v1/flashcards"`), css is no longer applied, although list of flashcards are still there as plain texts. That's why I commented out `@RequestMapping`.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
//@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/flashcards")
public class FlashcardController {

    private final FlashcardService flashcardService;

    public String listFlashcards(Model model) {
        List<FlashcardDto> flashcards = flashcardService.getFlashcards();
        model.addAttribute("flashcards", flashcards);
        return "flashcards-list";
    }
}
```

I tried putting `@GetMapping(path = "api/v1/flashcards", produces = "text/html")` on top of the
`listFlashcards()` function but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: At first, check the browser's developer tool and see if there is a specific error, possibly related to CORS. If not, then try to find out which endpoint is called to fetch the style and check whether it is correct or not. if the url is incorrect maybe relative url or adding baseUrl can be a solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used absolute path for css file by adding `/` at the beginning of href.

Before:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

After:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`

I don't quite understand why it worked though.